# how to use the state hook for dynamically created components in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to do is use useState for dynamically created components in React. In the code below I am, rendering the new components, but I cannot find a way to keep track of their state like I did for the hardcoded components. The new components are rendered when the user creates a new "post", causing new "posts" to be generated.

```
return (
      {
            results.map( (eachPost) =>
              { const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(true); },
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Card>
                  <Text>
                    {JSON.parse(eachPost).title}
                  </Text>
                  <Collapsible collapsed = {status}>
                    {JSON.parse(eachPost).content}
                  </Collapsible>
                </Card>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
     }
)
```

UPDATE: I need to know how I can re-render the page

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import EditScreenInfo from '../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';
import Collapsible from 'react-native-collapsible';
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';
import { CardStyleInterpolators } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import Post from './Post'
import RenderToLayer from 'material-ui/internal/RenderToLayer';
import { useForceUpdate } from './useForceUpdate'


async function createNewPost (titleAndContent : string){

    const post = {titleAndContent_: titleAndContent}

    try {

      await AsyncStorage.setItem('post' + Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000), JSON.stringify(post))

      
    } catch (e) {
      
      console.log(e)
    }
    //console.log(newPosts)

}



export default function NewsScreen({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) {

  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(true);
  const [status2, setStatus2] = React.useState(true);
  const [status3, setStatus3] = React.useState(true);
  const [renderedData, setRenderedData] = React.useState(new Array<string>());
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState('Please enter the details of the post in the format of title,content');
  const [, forceUpdate] = useState();


  const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
        console.log(result)
        return result;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
  };

  async function parseData() {

    const payments = await getData();

    if (payments) {

        const res = payments
        //.filter((e: any[]) => e[1] && e.includes('{'))
        //.map((e: any[]) => e[1]);
        
        setRenderedData(res);

        console.log(res)
    }

    return renderedData;
  }

  const results: string[] = []

  renderedData.forEach( (eachPost) => {

    if ((/\{"title.*}/g.test(eachPost[1]))) results.push(eachPost[1])

  })

  console.log(results)

    
  React.useEffect(() => {


    if (renderedData.length === 0) {
        parseData();
    }

    forceUpdate
  
  },[]);



  return (


    <View style={styles.container}>

        
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 25}}>News</Text>
         

          <View style = {{flexDirection: "row"}}> 


            <TextInput
                style={{ height: 40, width: 700, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                value = {input}
                onChangeText={text=>setInput(text)}
            />

            <Button
                onPress={()=> createNewPost(input)}
                title="Add post"
                color="blue"
                accessibilityLabel="A button to allow the admin to create a new post"
            />

            <Button 
                onPress = {useForceUpdate()}
                title="submit"
            
            />

          </View>

          <View>

          {

  
            results.map( (eachPost) =>

        
              <Post titleAndContent={JSON.parse(eachPost)}/>
              
              

            )

          }

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setStatus(!status)}>
                  <Card>

                      <Text>
                        Moore Park Lift Outage
                      </Text>


                        <Image        
                            source={{
                              
                              uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/Etr5xBn.png'
                                                
                            }}
                            style={{width: 20, height: 20, marginLeft: 10}}
                        >            
                        </Image>

                        <Collapsible collapsed = {status}>

                            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                              UPDATED 6 Aug 09:30 {'\n'} 
                              Details: Ongoing {'\n'} 
                              Lift 2 at Moore Park Light Rail is temporarily out of service. For assistance, ask staff.. {'\n'} 
                            </Text>
                            <Image        
                              source={{
                                uri: 'https://svg-clipart.com/svg/blue/PGaAIh0-blue-wheelchair-vector.svg',
                              }}
                              style={{width: 70, height: 90, marginTop: 30}}
                            >            
                            </Image>

                        </Collapsible>
                  </Card>

              </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setStatus2(!status2)}>

                  <Card>

                      <Text>Dulwich Hill Line running slow</Text>

                        <Image        
                            source={{

                              uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/iNjXQMW.png'
                            }}
                            style={{width: 20, height: 20, marginLeft: 10}}
                        >            
                        </Image>

                        <Collapsible collapsed = {status2}>

                          <Text>
                            The Dulwich Hill Line is running slow due to track-work being conducted between Lilyfield and Rozelle Bay
                          </Text>

                        </Collapsible>
                  </Card>

              </TouchableOpacity>

              
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setStatus3(!status3)}>

                  <Card >

                      <Text>Extra services running</Text>

                        <Image        
                            source={{
                              
                              uri: 'https://imgur.com/Etr5xBn'
                                                
                            }}
                            style={{width: 20, height: 20, marginLeft: 10}}
                        >            
                        </Image>

                        <Image        
                            source={{
                              
                              uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/Etr5xBn.png'

                            }}
                            style={{width: 20, height: 20, marginLeft: 10}}
                        >            
                        </Image>

                      <Collapsible collapsed = {status3}>
                        <Text>
                          Extra services will be running this week to help students get back to school
                        </Text>
                      </Collapsible>
                  </Card>
              </TouchableOpacity>   

      </View>

        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}
            title="Go back"
            color="blue"
            accessibilityLabel="A button to click so that you can go back to the home page"
          />

        </View>
        
  </View>


  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',

  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: '80%',
  },
  button: {
    margin: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  news:{
    flexDirection:'column',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  eachnews:{
    margin: 500,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    
  },
  textnews:{
    fontSize: 20,
},
});
```

Comment: Hi, you can put a state in a return. You should declare it outside of that or you can make infinite loop. If you want to use useState create a new component in other file.

Comment: I don't know how many state's I need, the components are generated dynamically

Comment: you only need 1, if you are learning try to check some tutorials about hwo react hooks works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need more knowledge related to basics of react.

You need a Post component
Post.js

```
export default (props) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState();

  return (<TouchableOpacity>

                <Card>

                  <Text>
                    {props.title}
                  </Text>

                  <Collapsible collapsed = {status}>

                    {props.content}

                  </Collapsible>


                </Card>

              </TouchableOpacity>);
  
  
  };
```

When u call Post
App.js

```
import Post from './Post.js'
export default App = ()
{
const result = [];
return (
results.map( (eachPost) =>{
              const eachPost = JSON.parse(eachPost);
              return (<Post title={eachPost.title} content={eachPost.content})/>)
            }
}
)
```

Comment: where do I define the Post component

Comment: in another file

Comment: I am new to React, so I don't know how all of this works. Why am I using props? I am using react native with functional style, how do I define the Post component

Comment: because u want pass that data to your childs. Read some of docs of react or a tutorial.

Comment: thanks. I just need to know how to access the data inside the props

Comment: you can pass what u want to ur component if you pass <Post title='hello'> you can access props.title and so on

Comment: Hi, just a follow up question, the posts are now rendering - but only when I refresh the page. I am trying to use forceUpdate to refresh the page using React.useEffect but it is not working

Comment: Edit you question with full code, I thinl issue is where u get results